# A global key was used multiple times inside one widgets child list

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

After closing the app, when I try to open it again, I'm getting the following error but it's only on iOS platform, Android works well.

[image]

I have looked around and there are several SO questions and issues about this problem but I couldn't solve it. I'm also using `bloc` pattern for managing state.

I have `GlobalKey<FormState>` in my `AuthenticateForm`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:low_code/blocs/authentication/authentication_bloc.dart';
import 'package:low_code/blocs/authentication/authentication_event.dart';
import 'package:low_code/helpers/app_localization/app_localizations.dart';

class AuthenticateForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthenticateFormState createState() => _AuthenticateFormState();
}

class _AuthenticateFormState extends State<AuthenticateForm> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String username;

  String password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppLocalizations appLocalizations = AppLocalizations.of(context);
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            onSaved: (String value) => username = value,
            initialValue: 'dms-bpm',
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: appLocalizations.translate('username')),
            // ignore: missing_return
            validator: (String value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter your ${appLocalizations.translate('username')}';
              }
            },
          ),
          TextFormField(
            onSaved: (String value) => password = value,
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: appLocalizations.translate('password')),
            initialValue: 'dms-bpm',
            // ignore: missing_return
            validator: (String value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter your ${appLocalizations.translate('password')}';
              }
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
            child: Text(appLocalizations.translate('login')),
            onPressed: () {
              _formKey.currentState.save();
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context)
                  ..dispatch(
                      Authenticate(username: username, password: password));
              }
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.615], locale en-GB)

Comment: each form should have only one child as i know

Comment: Try to Add Key on ListView,GridView SingleChildScrollView etc.. this will solve the issue as you are using the same key for two Scroll Widget

Comment: I add key all the `ListView`, `GridView`, `SingleChildScrollView` but it didnt solve it. @ArunR.Prajapati

Comment: @MuratAslan Form already has only one child which is a column

Comment: one textfield i mean

Comment: @MuratAslan So you're saying: "Each form should have only one textformfield widget". That's simply not the case and not how the forms work. Please review some form examples with Flutter https://medium.com/flutter-community/realistic-forms-in-flutter-part-1-327929dfd6fd

Comment: Hot Restart. Most errors are due to changes made

Comment: Add home property in main.dart file...

Answer (score 23):

Try stop and rerun you application instead of hot reloading. That solved my problem.

Comment: this can't be a solution. App must need a hot reload or restart

Comment: It does work @Mukta, try this option only once untill your problem gets resolved. Mine did

Comment: Still you don't have any idea about Global Key of Flutter. Notice  the question. He is using a single key for multiple Widget or Screen. Either he needs to use a list of Global keys or different naming single key. Still now I am disagree with your answer. Sorry

Answer (score 16):

In my case this error happened because I had a **initialRoute** property set, while instead I should set the **home** property:

```
class RouteTestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      //initialRoute: '/', //remove this
      home: FirstScreen(),  //this is the calling screen
      routes: {
        ExtractArgumentsScreen.routeName: (context) => ExtractArgumentsScreen(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

i just stopped the hot reload and restarted the app it worked for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29834684)

Answer (score 2):

In case you are getting the error when the app just started:
Add '/' route to the list of routes and restart.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I run the flutter app without adding
`home: BottomNavBar()`.
after getting an error I added `home: BottomNavBar()` and give hot reload (Command + s) which reproduce this error (A global key was used multiple times inside one widget child list).
Then I just reconnect my target device and run again, which fixed my issue.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness:Brightness.light,
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
        accentColor: Colors.blue,
        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
      ),
      home: BottomNavBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Try stop and rerun you application instead of hot reloading. That solved my problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your GlobalKey "final". I think the fact your global key is mutable might be creating this problem.

Comment: it dosn't effect on code. But obviously need to declare as final.

Answer (score 0):

just kill the app run (stop) and uninstall it then reinstall it again to reset the navigator state

Answer (score 0):

Just assign UniqueKey() to your ListView.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i was forgot add async await for main()

```
main() async {
  await initModul();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

initModul() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
      await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  instance.registerLazySingleton<SharedPreferences>(
    () => sharedPreferences,
  );

  instance.registerLazySingleton<AppSettingsSharedPreferences>(
      () => AppSettingsSharedPreferences(instance()));

  // for clear preferences:
  // AppSettingsSharedPreferences appSettingsSharedPreferences =
  // instance<AppSettingsSharedPreferences>();
  // appSettingsSharedPreferences.clear();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the calling screen in the `home:` property of the `MaterialApp()` object was returning null. After fixing it, I stopped the app and reran it.